# Can't compile Cocos2d-x project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, cocos2d-x

I've just installed Cocos2d-X and whenever i try to compile newly created project i got the following error.

I tried to uninstall and install java again and nothing changed.

I'm using the following command to compile.

```
> cocos.py compile -p android --android-studio
```

And i got the following Error :

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                                                                                              
* What went wrong:                                                                                         
A problem occurred configuring project ':libcocos2dx'.                                                     
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.                                                               
> javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema                                                                                                                                                                              
* Try:                                                                                                     
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option 
to get more log output.                                                                                                                  
BUILD FAILED
```

and sometimes i get this error

```
> Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
```

instead of

```
> javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
```

Comment: Go into proj.android-studio directory and run ./gradlew --stracktrace

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  For me uninstalling java 9 and installing java 8 did the trick.

If you are in Android studio you could go to File -> Project Structure and change the JDK Location to wherever you have java 8 installed

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand command line compile doesn't work for android-studio anymore.
Best way is to try install latest android-studio and latest cocos2d-x. Then build apk and test on device... 
First time you run android-studio it will download few things. And first compile for a projct will take ages.. but after that everything will be pretty fast